# Dell Airflow Baffle Alternative

Tags: dell-poweredge

I've noticed that the WX081 airflow baffle in the PowerEdge 1950 III obscures two of the three internal USB ports. Does anyone know if there's an alternative which does not obscure the ports?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unlikely that you'll be able to find an alternative.

I'd try cutting away those parts of the baffle that are in the way. Close up larger holes that you create to keep the airflow where it should be.

Alternatively, you could check if short extension cables solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Zac. I did suspect this may be the case but had to ask. Seems odd that they would design the mobo with the ports in that place and then design something else which would make them difficult to use...